# Obtaining unknown values in a cycle given only the sums of adjacent pairs?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, permutation-cycles

I have a cyclic set of $n$ unknown values $x_1 ... x_n$ that I am trying to obtain and a cyclic set of $n$ known values, each of which corresponds to $x_a + x_{a+1}$ with the n$^{th}$ value $y_{n,1}$ = $x_n + x_{1}$ wrapping around back to the start of the set.

This can be re-written as $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns:

$x_1 + x_2 = y_{1,2}\\x_2 + x_3 = y_{2,3}\\...\\x_{n-1} + x_n = y_{n-1,n}\\x_n + x_1 = y_{n,1}$

Given that the values of $y$ are known decimals, can the x values be obtained in any case other than $n=3$?

Apologies if my terminology is not perfect, I'm coming at this from a programming background.

Comment: When $n$ is odd, yes.  When $n$ is even, the sums do not uniquely determine the unknown values: you can add any vector of the form $(c,-c,c,-c,\ldots,c,-c)$ and the sums will be preserved.  However, that is the only obstruction, so one independent data point such as the one in Yorch’s answer is enough to determine the values.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_i = x_i + x_{i+1}$ where $x_{n+1} = x_1$.

If $n$ is even then you require that the sum of the odd $y_i$ is equal to the sum of the even $y_i$ and then every option for $x_1$ induces a solution that can be obtained in linear time easily by using $x_i = y_{i-1}-x_{i-1}$.

If $n$ is odd then note $x_i = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i)/2-y_2-y_4+\dots -y_{2\lfloor(n/2-1\rfloor}$ and every other value can be determined by using $x_i = y_{i-1}-x_{i-1}$.

Comment: Hopefully this allows you to code something useful :)